# angularjs - directive doesnt work in function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angularjs-directive

I try to use angular directive, it works fine if I put it normally to js file but if I try to put it to function it doesn't work:

```
function getCity(city){
    document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML=city;
    $.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="' + city + '")&format=json', function (data) {
       humi = data.query.results.channel.atmosphere.humidity;
    });
    var app = angular.module("weatApp", []);
    app.directive("humiGet", function() {
    return {
        template : [humi]
    };
    });
}
```

Comment: is getCity called anywhere ?

Comment: You must've forgotten to call getCity(). Please check.

Comment: It is called and document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML=city; works as it is called, but directive doesnt

Comment: why do you call the API using jquery? instead you can call using **$http** service in Angular itself. Also what are the errors in your console

Comment: When i searched up API I found example with jquery so I used it and Im not to familiar to Angular. An error that i get is Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=weatApp&p1=Error%3A…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A274)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4458
    at n (angular.js:340)
    at g (angular.js:4419)
    at eb (angular.js:4344)
    at c (angular.js:1676)
    at yc (angular.js:1697)
    at Zd (angular.js:1591)
    at angular.js:29013
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3057)

Comment: but it is not from this function

Answer (score 0):

humi may not be set by the time you call the directive:

```
function getCity(city){
    document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML=city;
    $.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="' + city + '")&format=json', function (data) {
        humi = data.query.results.channel.atmosphere.humidity;

        var app = angular.module("weatApp", []);
        app.directive("humiGet", function() {
           return { template : [humi] };
        });
    });
}
```

A better way would be to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
function getCity(city){
    document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML=city;
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text="' + city + '")&format=json', function (data) {
        humi = data.query.results.channel.atmosphere.humidity;
        var app = angular.module("weatApp", []);
        app.directive("humiGet", function() {
           return { template : [humi] };
        });
        deferred.resolve(true);
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}

// else where
getCity('Fargo').then(function () {
    // use directive here
});
```

Comment: It cant be it because if i change return { template : "whatever"} it still doesnt return anything in that function